# gnu screen: exit without prompt?

Tags: screen, exit, prompt, gnu-screen

I'm using gnu `screen` version 4.08.00 under linux. I know that I can exit `screen` via `Ctrl-a \`. However, when I type that, I am prompted to confirm that I really want to exit.  Is there a way from within a `screen` session to tell `screen` to immediately exit without any prompt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had originally gotten `screen` from the standard `Ubuntu` repo, and apparently, that version of `screen` makes use of this exit confirmation prompt, while the `git` version does not. Therefore, I uninstalled `screen` from the `Ubuntu` repo and built `screen` from the code in its `git` repo: https://git.savannah.gnu.org/git/screen.git .  That is version 4.99.0 .

Now, I am not prompted when exiting via `C-a \`